# I can't make questions_answers_foo plugin work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've downloaded the [questions_answers_foo](http://github.com/hasham2/questions_answers_foo/) plugin and placed it at vendor->plugins folder, as I usually do. Then, following its documentation, I ran rake `question_answers:install` and I get this in the output:

> ArgumentError: wrong # of arguments(0
>   for 1)

I followed the installation steps but I get this error. Does anybody know where can I find the method that it's causing the error. I already checked the plugin's files but I have no clue yet.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
rake question_answers:install --trace
```

Comment: where should I run that? because I'm using the NetBeans 'Debug/Run rake task' read-only option to run it. And from the NetBeans console I get an error saying that 'trace' is not recognized as a valid command.

Comment: Sorry, I've never used NetBeans.  --trace is standard UNIX command line option syntax.  NetBeans ought to have an options string or even provide an explicit option for this since --trace is extremely common.  If it doesn't then can you open up a shell and run this from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

I notice that this plugin expects you to have a field in your User model called 'login' - can you be certain that you have that?  If you are using nifty_authentication for instance, then you will possibly have a field called 'username' (depending on your setup) instead of 'login'

Comment: I do have a 'login' field in my User model.